# Can an .EXE file be executed on its own if it is saved in a different format as .pdf or .csv?

Tags: security

We have an MVC application where there are modules in which user can upload files like[.wav,Pdf,.csv].

So, I am working on making the application secure by not allowing any harmfull files like .exe. For this I am checking the incoming files with their extensions, if they are any of the 3 file types[.wav,pdf,.csv] I am allowing it to save in the file system, if it's an .exe I am not.

So in this scenario someone might save an .exe file as .csv and pass the filter I have put to check for incoming extensions and that file gets saved in the app server. If they do so can this .exe file be executed in the application server on its own even if its extension is not .exe?

Comment: You might want to research how Windows "opens" files. See [CreateProcess](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-createprocessw) and [ShellExecuteEx](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/shell/launch), not so much for their programming usage but for all the opportunities and complexity they provide. Consider extensions like .cpl and .msc. That should lead you to not using the system's filesystem for a user-data storage system.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of checking file extensions, read the magic from the start of the file. `.exe` files all begin with 2 bytes, (ascii) `mz` / (hex) `4D 5A`, which represent that the file is `DOS MZ executable` (exe). Even by renaming the file, this magic doesn't change.

Solution:
Read the first 2 bytes of the file, if it's equal to `4D 5A`, then block it. Or even better, read the magic of the file to see if it's a `wav`, `pdf`, or `csv` file. A full(ish) list of file magic's is available at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_file_signatures

Comment: Also there are libraries that give you the real mime type by inspecting the magic bytes. Rely on whitelists instead of blacklists (ie. only allow types from a known good list, and not disallow types from a blacklist).

Comment: You'll get a false positive for a CSV file where the first two characters of the data contain are "mz" - if you're going to use heuristics, they should be a bit more robust, users are buggers for uploading data that hits weak ones!

Comment: @Rob oh yeah true... I didn't think of that.